# What is the meaning of each value in the output of Super Pixel Segmentation in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

I am currently working in Super Pixel segmentation. I am using Simple Linear Iterative Clustering(SLIC). This is the code

```
# load the image and apply SLIC and extract (approximately)
# the supplied number of segments
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
segments = slic(img_as_float(image), n_segments = 100, sigma = 5)

# show the output of SLIC
fig = plt.figure("Superpixels")
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.imshow(mark_boundaries(img_as_float(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)), segments))
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

And I got the output of segments as

```
array([[ 0,  0,  0, ...,  7,  7,  7],
       [ 0,  0,  0, ...,  7,  7,  7],
       [ 0,  0,  0, ...,  7,  7,  7],
       ...,
       [76, 76, 76, ..., 84, 84, 84],
       [76, 76, 76, ..., 84, 84, 84],
       [76, 76, 76, ..., 84, 84, 84]])
```

What does each value in the segments mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your usage makes me think that this is the slic function from scikit right?

Which in [its documentation](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.segmentation.html#skimage.segmentation.slic) says what it returns:

> **Returns:**
>   labels : 2D or 3D array Integer mask indicating segment labels.

This means that it will be an image like the one you supplied and it will tell you for each pixel what is their label. So, if you have the value 1 in the certain pixel of this returned image, that means that it belongs to the cluster 1 and so on up to the value you supply in `n_segments = 100`.

If you have doubts, just leave a comment :)